# Disable google search in Chrome for custom TLDs

Tags: google-chrome, url

We are working with a custom top level domain per developer which points to it's localhost, so internally we would have url's like this

- companywebsite.com.john
- companywebsite.com.mike
- subdomain1.companywebsite.com.john
- ..
- subdomain99.companywebsite.com.john

The problem is that every time when we need to access a sub-domain for the first time(and we have a lot of them) chrome always redirects to a google search, then after a few attempts, asks if we actually mean

http://subdomain99.companywebsite.com.john/

So, my question is, how could I set up chrome to always parse that kind of url as a url not a search.

Thank's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end this is what we ended up doing:

```
1. go to **Settings**
2. in Search section click on **Manage search engines**
3. Scroll down to the bottom until you find an empty entry
4. Fill in these values: (noSearch, null, http://%s)
5. Scroll back up in the list, find it and click **Make default**
```

Answer (score 6):

For my case I found an easy solution by chance, add a forawrd slash `/` at the end of your url and chrome will revert to url, in your example: `companywebsite.com.john/`

Check the screenshots below:

**Before you add slash**

[image]

**when you add the slash at the end, Chrome will translate it to a url**

[image]